# Sink to the virtual v4l2 device

Tags: linux, gstreamer

I have tried an [example](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-v4l2sink.html) on Ubuntu 19.04

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video10
```

But gstreamer fails

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Cannot identify device '/dev/video10'.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(609): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0:
system error: No such file or directory
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Why it doesn't work? I haven't found this in the documentation, do I need to create /dev/video10 somehow?

I did the same for the default device /dev/video1, but it is an input camera device on my laptop:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink 
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Device '/dev/video1' is not a output device.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(639): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0:
Capabilities: 0x4a00000
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: Well yes, you need to create a virtual/loopback device. GStreamer just streams data to existing devices. If they do not exist there is nothing it can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of your questions suggests you would like to write to a virtual video device. v4l2 devices can be both input and output video devices. Your camera is a video input (capture) device. Directing a v4l2sink (so an endpoint of the pipeline) in gstreamer will likely fail.

You can however generate a virtual output device. What you are looking for is something like the [v4l2-loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) device. It allows you to generate a virtual `/dev/video10` device like this:

```
modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=10
```

Comment: Does it makes sense to add to the gstreamer documentation?

Comment: After created virtual device(/dev/video6) I tried this command; 

"gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5002 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec !  v4l2sink device=/dev/video6 "

but I still got same error;

ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Sink:v4l2sink0: Device '/dev/video6' is not a output device. It works with autovideosink but I could not directing to the device.

Comment: @Purgoufr you need queue and videoconvert apparently:  gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5002 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! queue ! videoconvert ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video6

Comment: @AwokeKnowing I didn't know about queue. Thanks for info :)

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution for the same error message: recreate the v4l2loopback interface:

```
sudo rmmod -f v4l2loopback
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

This might apply to others experiencing the error message from the original question, **but** who are already aware they need a v4l2loopback device as gstreamer sink.

When trying to stream a video to the existing v4l2loopback device I streamed to using ffmpeg before, I got the same error message

> Device '/dev/video0' is not a output device.

**Investigation**

When comparing the state of a working loopback video device and a non-working one (i.e. after writing to it with ffmpeg) with `v4l2-ctl --all -d 0` using `diff`, I found the following difference :

```
--- working     2020-11-19 18:03:52.499440518 +0100
+++ non-working 2020-11-19 18:03:57.472802868 +0100
@@ -3,21 +3,18 @@
         Card type        : GPhoto2 Webcam
         Bus info         : platform:v4l2loopback-000
         Driver version   : 5.9.8
-        Capabilities     : 0x85208002
-                Video Output
+        Capabilities     : 0x85208000
                 Video Memory-to-Memory
                 Read/Write
                 Streaming
                 Extended Pix Format
                 Device Capabilities
-        Device Caps      : 0x05208002
-                Video Output
+        Device Caps      : 0x05208000
                 Video Memory-to-Memory
                 Read/Write
                 Streaming
                 Extended Pix Format
 Priority: 0
-Video output: 0 (loopback in)
 Format Video Output:
         Width/Height      : 960/640
         Pixel Format      : 'YU12' (Planar YUV 4:2:0)
```

Somehow that "Video Output" capability is required for gstreamer to work successfully and taken away by my previous ffmpeg call.
The behaviour only occured when I loaded the v4l2loopback module with the `exclusive_caps=1` option, see [1](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/198#issuecomment-723256068).

The solution was to unload / load the v4l2loopback kernel  commands, forcefully removing the v4l2loopback kernel module and adding it again using rmmod / modprobe (see above).